# Jenkins - IBM UrbanCode - AWS & Azure cloud

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, urbancode

For [continuous delivery](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/493), we do manual deployment after generating binary artifacts from Jenkins pipeline(in an automated process).

Further, 
for [continuous deployment](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/493), we would like to use IBM UrbanCode tool to automate provisioning and configuration of services  on  both AWS cloud and Azure cloud.

---

1) Does IBM UrbanCode tool help provisioning and configuration of services to AWS and Azure cloud?

2) Does Jenkins support plugin to work with IBM UrbanCode deploy tool? To deploy on AWS and Azure cloud

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both of those questions.

1) There are plugins for both AWS and Azure. These allow you to dynamically create an provision instances in either cloud. If you just need to deploy to a predefined instance, UCD will do that out of the box. 
https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/iis-ms-deploy-ibmucd/
https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/amazonec2/

2) The Jenkins Publisher plugin will do what you need to get the binaries into UCD: https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/jenkins/

Comment: We are trying to have a vendor neutral API to provision infrastructure in cloud. That means... today we may use AWS cloud, and then Azure and then cloud be a private cloud(type1 hypervisor)

Comment: There is no "vendor neutral API". If you build you UCD component processes flexible, then you can swap out which plugin (AWS or Azure) that you use.